# Problema com cURL, pegar corpo da mensagem mesmo com http != 200

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho uma requisição na minha API:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'link da api');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );

$db_save_user = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); //recupera o json quando o httpstatus = 200
$http_status = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

Utilizando o `postman`, eu recebo o erro esperado, e o `json` de resposta
Gostaria de utilizar essas informações pra caso o usuário acesse a página ou atualize a página, invés de criar um novo usuário, ele prosseguir com o cadastro setando as informações que já estão salvas no banco, mas não estou conseguindo achar o método pra recuperar essas informações quando há o `httpstatus != 200` de jeito nenhum!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, em `js/jquery`, em uma requisição `ajax`, quando há a falha do servidor, mesmo assim há a possibilidade de recuperar o `json` de resposta:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "link da api", 
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(returnjson){
        console.log(returnjson.id_customer);
        return true;
    },
    error: function(returnjson) {
        if(returnjson.status == 409){
            console.log(returnjson.responseJSON.id_customer);
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("Ocorreu algum erro, tente novamente ou entre em contato com o suporte técnico.");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Você já conferiu se o comando "curl_exec($ch)", retorna dados sobre a requisição? Acredito que algum dos métodos do Curl fazem com que esse comportamento ocorra. Usar outro HTTP client resolveria seu problema também. Isso não é uma opção?

Comment: Ele está retornando `bool(false)`.... É uma opção, porém se possível queria fazer com o cURL

Comment: O comando *curl -I http://www.example.org* devolve o http status code da requisição. Consegue verificar qual o método correspondente para seu client? Talvez isso ajude.

Comment: Desculpa @andreybleme, acho que não entendi a sua pergunta

Comment: Além disso, use o Uri com a barra final para evitar WCF responder com o 307.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está exatamente na terceira linha.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
```

Segundo o a [documentação do CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.html):

> A long parameter set to 1 tells the library to fail the request if the
>   `HTTP CODE` returned is equal to or larger than 400. The default action
>   would be to return the page normally, ignoring that code.

Traduzindo (editado para melhor compreensão):

> O parâmetro definido como "1" diz para a biblioteca "matar"
>   a requisição se o `HTTP CODE` retornado for igual ou maior a 400. A ação
>   padrão seria retornar a página normalmente, ignorando esse código.

**Portanto que está ocorrendo é o seguinte:**

Usando o `true` no `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` você está encerrando o CURL quando o `HTTP_CODE` não for 200, como apontado. Como resultado você não consegue obter o resultado da página, tampouco conseguirá fazer o `json_decode()`.

**Solução:**

Remova a linha (`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );`) ou torne-a como `false`. Isso irá fazer com que o CURL retorne a página mesmo se o `HTTP CODE` for maior ou igual a 400!

Comment: grande, funcionou :)